# Why do two columns gets updated when I specified only one to be updated? and how to correct it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update `EventsTbl.Year` if `EventsTbl.Id` is equals to `ProceedsTbl.EventsId` and `EventsTbl.Year` is not equals to `ProceedsTbl.Year` but both the `EventsTbl.Year` and the `ProceedsTbl.Year`gets updated (They switched values).

Some `EventsTbl` row have multiple `ProceedsTbl` row so I tried using `left join` and `outer apply` but the results are not what I expected.

```sql
UPDATE  EventsTbl
SET     EventsTbl.Year = ProceedsTbl.Year
FROM    EventsTbl LEFT JOIN ProceedsTbl
ON      EventsTbl.Id = ProceedsTbl.EventsId
WHERE   EventsTbl.Year != ProceedsTbl.Year
```

```sql
UPDATE  EventsTbl
SET     EventsTbl.Year = ProceedsTbl.Year
FROM    EventsTbl OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ProceedsTbl WHERE EventsTbl.Id = ProceedsTbl.TMSId AND EventsTbl.FiscalYear != ProceedsTbl.FiscalYear)
WHERE   EventsTbl.Year != ProceedsTbl.Year
```

**EventsTbl**

```sql
+-----+------+
| Id  | Year |
+-----+------+
|  64 |    0 |
|  76 |    0 |
| 124 | 2018 |
| 125 | 2018 |
| 305 | 2019 |
| 456 | 2019 |
| 555 | 2019 |
+-----+------+
```

**ProceedsTbl**

```sql
+----------+----------+------+
|    Id    | EventsId | Year |
+----------+----------+------+
|  8980909 |       64 | 2018 |
|  8980910 |       64 | 2018 |
|  8980911 |       64 | 2018 |
| 12380912 |       76 | 2018 |
| 12380913 |       76 | 2018 |
| 12380914 |       76 | 2018 |
| 12380915 |       76 | 2018 |
| 32880916 |      124 | 2018 |
| 32880917 |      124 | 2018 |
| 32880918 |      124 | 2018 |
| 32880919 |      124 | 2018 |
| 32880920 |      124 | 2018 |
| 56080920 |      125 | 2019 |
| 56080921 |      125 | 2019 |
| 56080922 |      125 | 2019 |
| 56080923 |      125 | 2019 |
| 61480923 |      305 | 2018 |
| 61480924 |      305 | 2018 |
| 61480925 |      305 | 2018 |
| 78280925 |      555 | 2018 |
| 78280926 |      555 | 2018 |
| 78280927 |      555 | 2018 |
| 78280928 |      555 | 2018 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

**Desired Result**

```sql
+-----+------+
| Id  | Year |
+-----+------+
|  64 | 2018 |
|  76 | 2018 |
| 124 | 2018 |
| 125 | 2019 |
| 305 | 2018 |
| 555 | 2018 |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: For Id 555, which value you want? 2018 from ProceedsTbl or 2019 from EventsTbl?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I updated it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first join with distinct value from ProceedsTbl. Something like below will work for you.

```
UPDATE  EventsTbl
SET     EventsTbl.Year = PT.Year
FROM    EventsTbl JOIN (SELECT EventsId, MAX(Year) Year
                        FROM ProceedsTbl
                        GROUP BY EventsId) PT
ON      EventsTbl.Id = PT.EventsId
WHERE   EventsTbl.Year != PT.Year
```

Comment: I would add that there is no need to do a LEFT JOIN. INNER JOIN is the required type since records in EventsTbl without matching records in ProceedsTbl should not get updated. In addition, in the desired results the Year value for record with EventId=555 should be updated to 2018.

Comment: Thanks @ManosAnastasiadis and @Ankit Bajpai but the values still switches so the `Year` in both tables are still not equal.

Comment: What values you are getting?

Comment: The zero years are gone but 2018 and 2019 just keeps switching. Maybe it's because my `SET` and `WHERE` are contradicting and the sequence of it? I also tried removing the `MAX(YEAR)` and grouping it with `Year` as well.

Comment: This query is working fine on dbfiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c6a6e0d4072d4079617e3c1038505a8d

Comment: Thanks. I was just reviewing my data and I have a few `ProceedsTbl` rows with 2 different `Year` with the same `EventsId` that must be why it was switching on my end. Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer since it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining with the whole table ProceedsTbl
Try to join with distinct values sets in ProceedsTbl of Year and ID like

```
UPDATE  EventsTbl
SET     EventsTbl.Year = ProceedsTbl.Year
FROM    EventsTbl LEFT JOIN (Select Distinct EventsID,Year from ProceedsTbl) ProceedsTbl
ON      EventsTbl.Id = ProceedsTbl.EventsId
WHERE   EventsTbl.Year != ProceedsTbl.Year
```